# Einstein photeectric effect and compton effect

Tags: photons, electrons, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

In compton effect, the x-ray photon striking the electron imparts some of its energy to the electron and a photon of lesser frequency is scattered. Also, to conserve the angular momentum(i don't know too much about it), whole of the energy of photon can't be absorbed by the electron.
However, in einstein's photoelectric equation, it is said that the whole energy 'hf' is used( some part in pulling it outside the metal surface and the remaining in increasing its kinetic energy). Then, the whole explanation must be wrong of photoelectric effect as whole energy of photon can't be absorbed by an electron. 
Please notify me wherever I m going wrong.

Comment: In the photoelectric effect the chunk of metal that the photoelectron is ejected from can mop up any stray momentum. In Compton scattering the electron is isolated so this can't happen.

Comment: But the book i m reading has written that the electron is loosely bounded.

Comment: In the photoelectric effect, the electron is bound to an atom. In the compton scattering, the electron is considered to be free.

Comment: But it should not matter if we are giving enough energized photons.

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: Dinesh new millennium physics

Comment: Ok. What is your question? What do you want to know?

Comment: A free electron cannot absorb a real photon. But in the photoelectric effect, the electron is not free. That's the whole point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67645/discussion-between-arthur-and-gurbir-singh).

Comment: Duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163385/conservation-of-energy-and-momentum-in-photoelectric-effect

Comment: Does the fact that the thermal speed of an electron at $300\,\rm K$ is roughly $10^5 \,\rm m\,s^{-1}$ and so its momentum is roughly $10^{-25} \, \rm kg\, m\,s^{-1}$ whilst the momentum of a $500\,\rm nm$ photon is approximately $10^{-27}\, \rm kg\, m\,s^{-1}$ have any relevance?