# Condition of Photoelectric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

To perform photoelectric effect, should the metal piece kept in vacuum or in a tube filled with any specific gas?

Answer (score 1):

The lower the amount of gas in the tube, the better are the chances of electrons reaching the positive electrode since gas molecules create obstacles for the electrons. The photoelectric effect already has a low success rate, now if gas molecules also create obstacles in the electrons' paths, the success rate will be further reduced. So it's better to have as less gas in the tube as possible.

Ideally, we'd expect the tubes to be devoid of any air, but in reality we can have tubes with a very low pressure as tubes with **no air** will be very difficult to make.

Please see user John Rennie's excellent answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/163390/208199) about the success rate of photoelectric effect.